# Enthought Canopy, pip not installing freshest github commit

Tags: enthought, canopy

I'm really perplexed by this behavior:

I am installing a github repo using pip with the Canopy Command Prompt in Enthought Canopy version 1.5.2

When I install a package from github, it clones the file, installs and says everything is up to date and even changes the version number, but the imported package is still the old version

For instance, I change the names of a function from version 7.1.1 to 7.1.2.  When I go to install the latest version, pip tells me I have installed version 7.1.2, but the changes are not taking place in the actual install when I import the file in the Canopy Editor, in fact a simple help(package) is showing the old version as still installed.  **So pip in the Canopy Command Prompt is telling me I am installing the latest version, but when I import that package in the actual Canopy Editor, the older version is installed.**

I have restarted my kernel, closed the Enthought program, but neither seem to fix the problem.

Comment: If your report is accurate, then you must have the old version still installed somewhere. After `import mypack`, what is `mypack.__file__` ?

Comment: I read an article about needing to upgrade my canopy version, now I have 1.5.5 and the issue is fixed.

Comment: Good. This was probably due to a build of pip that was not properly handling Canopy's virtual environments. Could probably have been resolved by updating pip, but updating everything is even better. Suggest that you write up your own answer and formally accept it so that it's clear that the question has been resolved.